# How can I check if Google services are blocked for my current user?

Tags: c++, firebase, ping, great-firewall-of-china

We're using Google's Firebase in a mobile app we're working on. Firebase doesn't seem to work in China. This is probably due to the nation-wide **block** of Google services there. Additionally, Firebase can be **slow** to initialize its remote config. (seconds) There are some variables that we need during the initial phase of the app. For instance A/B onboarding and segmenting.

### I'm looking for a way to distinguish between users that either:

- A) will never have access (e.g. China)
- B) have access but have to wait a couple of seconds

Can I just ping www.google.com (or better, 8.8.8.8), or is there an official way to check if services are blocked?
Should I try to reach googleapis.com?

The app is mostly in C++ mixed with Objective-C and java.